# "How to write subquery for different count of carton_id for different delivery_id

Tags: sql

I have two tables one is carton table  and another table name is deliveries_shipped, both table are having two column name same that is delivery_id column and another column name which is same, and the name is carton_id.
so I want only those delivery_Id which are having different counts of carton_id in both table......result should be

`delivery_id|count_of_carton_carton_id|count_of_deliveries_shipped_carton_id`

So for every delivery_id should have different count result will look like for eg:
 `0096219353|4|3|`?

I have wrote one query

```
SELECT  c.delivery_id, 
    COUNT(c.carton_id) AS count_of_carton,
    COUNT(ds.carton_id) AS count_of_deliveries_shipped
FROM carton AS c 
LEFT JOIN deliveries_shipped AS ds 
ON c.delivery_id = ds.delivery_id AND c.carton_id <> ds.carton_id 
GROUP BY c.delivery_id;
```

By executing query results are coming however the repetition of count are coming, so I want to know how to write the subquery for above question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aggregated  result you should use having (and not where)

```
select  c.delivery_id
,count(c.carton_id) as count_of_carton
,count(ds.carton_id) as count_of_deliveries_shipped
from carton as c 
left join deliveries_shipped as ds on c.delivery_id=ds.delivery_id 

group by c.delivery_id 
having count_of_carton<>count_of_deliveries_shipped
```

The where clause is evaluated  before the calculation of the aggregation so in sql  there is the having clause fo check the result based  on aggreagted values